# Get latest value in the group of records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this records table which I save weight, age and other biometrics in it.
Now I want to fetch the latest value of every biometric for every day so I can draw a chart.
The piece of code I'm using to fetch data from db before processing it is like the following:

```
 Records::where("user",$uid)->
     where("type", "biometric" )->  // record type
     where("fk", $bid )->    //biometric type
     where("datetime","<" ,$range->max)->
     where("datetime",">" ,$range->min)->
     groupBy( "datee" )->
     selectRaw("  max(amount)  as 'damount' , max(unit) as 'unit' ,   date(datetime) as 'datee'  ")->
     orderBy("datee","desc")->
     get(); 
    // !! Should change max values with the latest record in the group !!
```

Which `datee` is date of the day.
Say some users add more than one weight biometrics in a day so unit and damount should be the unit and value of lastest record of that day.

What can I use instead of max() to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What dialect of sql are you using and what version?

Comment: You could also skip datetime stuff entirely, `order by` an autoincrement id, order in descending (`desc`) order and use `limit 1` to only get the last inserted record everytime.

Comment: @KevinY mysql it is

Comment: @geertjanknapen order by after select is not my concern here. You can just ignore it

Comment: No, you can use that to get the last record inserted in the table.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps:

```
Records::where("user",$uid)
    ->where(["type" => "biometric", "fk" => $bid])
    ->whereBetween(DB::raw("DATE('datetime')"), array($range->max, $range->min))
    ->groupBy("datetime")->latest()->get();
```

Comment: It doesn't. one vote up for your where and whereBeetween but select part is what I want...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
Records::where("user",$uid)
->where("type", "biometric")
->where("fk", $bid)  
->where("datetime","<" ,$range->max)
->where("datetime",">" ,$range->min)
->latest()
->groupBy('datetime')
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. What does this latest do. Does it get latest record before group by or latest of the group for every group after group by?

Comment: You can view the latest explanation at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#latest-oldest

Comment: Based on the document it's just a order by date nothing more...